# Pass an array from jQuery POST to C# WebApi

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an array from a jQuery POST to a C# WebApi service, but I get the following error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#btn").click(function ()
        {
          var purchases = { dealid1: ["2", "3", "4"], theatid1: "5", mouvid1: "408", bookdt1: "10/11/2015", shtime1: "11:00AM", fbid1: "100" };
           $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                data: { purchases },
                url: "api/purchase",
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        });
    });
<input type="button" value="mybtn" id="btn" />
```

WebApi code:

```
 public object post([FromBody] purchase purchases)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(jsonvalues(purchases));
    }

    private object jsonvalues(purchase purchases)
    {
        object result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < purchases.dealid1.Length; i++)//I got error here//
        {
           int count= purchases.dealid1.Count();
            dealid = purchases.dealid1;
            string arr = dealid[i];
        }
            theatid = purchases.theatid1;
            mouvid = purchases.mouvid1;
            bookdt = purchases.bookdt1;
            shtime = purchases.shtime1;
            fbid = purchases.fbid1;
    }
 public class purchase
{
    public string[] dealid1 { get; set; }
    public string theatid1 { get; set; }
    public string mouvid1 { get; set; }
    public string bookdt1 { get; set; }
    public string shtime1 { get; set; }
    public string fbid1 { get; set; }

}
```

I am able to get other values like `theatid1`, `mouvid1`, etc.  But `dealid1` is not accessible. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got error here? Which error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try changing `data: { purchases }` to `data: purchases`. You wrap an object into an object. Why?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta; "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev:still i got the same error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: data: JSON.stringify( purchases ); replace this line and try it.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta:Working fine..Thank you so much..

Comment: @Unnikrishnan.S, Welcome buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#btn").click(function ()
    {
      var purchases = { dealid1: ["2", "3", "4"], theatid1: "5", mouvid1: "408", bookdt1: "10/11/2015", shtime1: "11:00AM", fbid1: "100" };
       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify( purchases ),
            url: "api/purchase",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    });
});
```